# How to get multiple substrings plus extra number from String in Java?

Tags: java, regex

Let's assume we have the following String:

```
(form_component_34=="Yes"||case_attribute_37==3&&case_attribute_40?has_content)
```

All I want to do, is to get the operands of it:

- form_component_34
- case_attribute_37
- case_attribute_40

They will always start with the string "form_component_" or "case_attribute_", and will have a number (as an ID) after it. I assume I should use regexp.

Could any of you please help me out?

Comment: So you want values like `34` , `37 ` etc ?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, I wanted to get the full component names with numbers, like "form_component_34".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?:form_component_|case_attribute_)\\d+
```

Java code:

```
String str = "(form_component_34==\"Yes\"||case_attribute_37==3&&case_attribute_40?has_content)";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(?:form_component_|case_attribute_)\\d+");
    ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
    while (m.find())
    {
        matches.add(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println(matches);
```

Output:

```
[form_component_34, case_attribute_37, case_attribute_40]
```

See [Ideone DEMO](http://ideone.com/bc1VrY)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PatternMatching
{
    public static void main( String args[] ){

      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String line = "(form_component_34==\"Yes\"||case_attribute_37==3&&case_attribute_40?has_content)";
      String pattern = "(?:form_component_|case_attribute_)\\d+";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
       while(m.find()) {
         System.out.println(""+m.group());
      }
   }
}
```